# Javascript Validating Numbers xhtml

Tags: javascript

I was working on some javascript homework and it states as follows:

-validate that the Customer ID is a Number, not a string.  Also all Customer IDs are numbers between 3000 and 3999.  All 4 digit numbers. Validate that all Customer IDs are numbers between 3000 and 3999.

-validate that the AcctNo is a Number, not a string.   And the number is between 90000 and 99999.

As I was working on the code, the part with the numbers always gave me errors, as I searched on the web for help, it came up with //

Any help is nice, thanks (:

Xhtml

```
    <head>
           <script type = 'text/javascript'>
             //  <![CDATA[
   $('#submit').click(function(){
validateRange();
validateRa();    
})

 function validateRange() {
        var txtVal = document.getElementById("CustomerID").value;
 var txtVal1=parseInt(txtVal);
        if (txtVal1 >= 3000 && txtVal1 <= 3999) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            alert('Please enter a number between 3000-3999');
            return false;
    }
    // ]]
     function validateRa() {
        var txtVal1 = document.getElementById("AcctNo").value;
         var txtVal2=parseInt(txtVal1);

        if (txtVal2 >= 90000 && txtVal2 <= 99999) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            alert('Please enter a number between 90000-99999');
            return false;
    }
       // ]]
</script>
        <title>Account Lookup</title>


    </head>
    <body>
       <h1> Please Provide Your Information</h1>
    <p><input type="text" id="AcctNo" value="Account Number"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="CustomerID" value="CustomerID" onchange="validateRange()"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="Type" value="Account Type" onchange="validateRange()"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="balance" value="Balance"/></p>


    <p class="submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" id="submit" /><button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button></p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need braces around the `else`.

Comment: Although, that should still work I guess, the thing is you don't need the `else` at all.

Comment: use id instead of name in html
http://jsfiddle.net/2w663kb0/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2w663kb0/

use id insted of name in html

html

```
<h1> Please Provide Your Information</h1>
    <p><input type="text" id="AcctNo" value="Account Number"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="CustomerID" value="CustomerID" onchange="validateRange()"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="Type" value="Account Type" onchange="validateRange()"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="balance" value="Balance"/></p>


    <p class="submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" id="submit" /><button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button></p>
```

js

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
validateRange();
validateRa();    
})

 function validateRange() {
        var txtVal = document.getElementById("CustomerID").value;
 var txtVal1=parseInt(txtVal);
        if (txtVal1 >= 3000 && txtVal1 <= 3999) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            alert('Please enter a number between 3000-3999');
            return false;
    }
    // ]]
     function validateRa() {
        var txtVal1 = document.getElementById("AcctNo").value;
         var txtVal2=parseInt(txtVal1);

        if (txtVal2 >= 90000 && txtVal2 <= 99999) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            alert('Please enter a number between 90000-99999');
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var txtVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("CustomerID").value) || 0;
```

And

```
var txtVal1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("AcctNo").value) || 0;
```

Also:

```
else {//<-- braces,since it has multiple lines
   alert('Please enter a number between 3000-3999');
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your else condition

you need to include braces in the else block too
So you must have

```
else
     {
        alert('Please enter a number between 3000-3999');
        return false;
     }
```

and

```
      else
         {
            alert('Please enter a number between 90000-99999');
            return false;
         }
```

Also

```
        var newtxtval = parseInt(txtval);
```

add the above line in both the functions and it will work

Answer (score 0):

1. You have the `name` of the text boxes as `CustomerID` and `AcctNo` not the `id` of the text boxes. So when your validation function accessing them using `document.getElementById` method will always give null reference, hence it will give java script error whenever you change the content of the `CustomerID` text box.
2. Function `validateRa()` is not at all called in your code, which is used to validate the account number.